# Spring application.yaml doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, yaml

I'm trying to config some JPA and Hibernate properties in yaml file, but the problem arises when I use @Value("${$hibernate.show_sql}") in my JpaConfig.

The error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private java.lang.Boolean
>   com.movieGo.JpaConfig.showSql; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Boolean];
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
>   boolean value [${spring.hibernate.show_sql}]

I write my application.yml like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/hello
    username: root
    password:

  hibernate:
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    hbm2ddl.auto: update
    show_sql: false
```

I use @Value like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = HelloApplication.class)

class JpaConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

@Value("${spring.dataSource.driverClassName}")
private String driver;
@Value("${spring.dataSource.url}")
private String url;
@Value("${spring.dataSource.username}")
private String username;
@Value("${spring.dataSource.password}")
private String password;
@Value("${spring.hibernate.dialect}")
private String dialect;
@Value("${spring.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
private String hbm2ddlAuto;
@Value("${spring.hibernate.show_sql}")
private Boolean showSql;
...
}
```

It seems Spring regards `show_sql` as a String type, but
How can I specify a Boolean type in .yml ?
New to Spring mvc, eager seeking help.

Comment: Try it wihout the second "$":   @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")

Comment: Which is it, `"${$hibernate.show_sql}"` or `"${spring.hibernate.show_sql}"`?

Comment: I'm sorry.'${$hibernate.show_sql}'is a mistake in writing.. As you can see in my code, actually I use "${spring.hibernate.show_sql}" when the error occurs.

Comment: Your library is reading everything as strings. You can see that from the value for `password`: since it is empty this is the same as specifying `null` which would normally be loaded as `null` in Java as well unless you explictily load everything as strings.

Comment: But..how can I fix that?